# Is there a way to use the listings package together with mathpartir's mathpar

Tags: listings

I'm trying to typeset a small-step semantics for a programming language. My plan was to use the mathpartir package for writing the inference rules and the listing package to typeset the language fragments.

If I use the two packages together in a regular math environment everything seems to work alright, as is shown in the first example from the following image. However, if I try to use the mathpar environment from mathpartir then **the result is incorrectly shifted to the right**, as is shown in the second example.

The mathpartir environment is very convenient because it automatically organizes the formulas by putting as many formulas on each line as it fits. **Is there some workaround to get the listings module to work together with mathpar?** If not, is there at least a way I can figure out why the result looks wrong? If this is a bug in the packages I don't know which package would be to blame.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  % without this the \hbox is not strictly necessary
  basicstyle={\ttfamily},
}

\begin{document}
% Works fine:
\[
  \infer{A \hbox{\lstinline!a!} A}{B \hbox{\lstinline!a!} B}
\]
% Weird shift:
\begin{mathpar}
  \infer{A \hbox{\lstinline!a!} A}{B \hbox{\lstinline!a!} B}
\end{mathpar}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I minimised the example to isolate the issue even further.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't trace it all but as usual in these kinds of cases it helps to set the problematic code in a box first
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  % without this the \hbox is not strictly necessary
  basicstyle={\ttfamily},
}

\begin{document}
% Works fine:
\[
  \infer{A \hbox{\lstinline!a!} A}{B \hbox{\lstinline!a!} B}
\]
% Weird shift:
\newbox\bA
\setbox\bA\hbox{\lstinline!a!}
\begin{mathpar}
  \infer{A \usebox\bA{} B}{A \usebox\bA{} B}
\end{mathpar}
\end{document}
```

---

Actually if it is enough to locally restore `\par` to the value listings expects (the resetting is not undone so only use, as here, in a group):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  % without this the \hbox is not strictly necessary
  basicstyle={\ttfamily},
}

\begin{document}
% Works fine:
\[
  \infer{A \hbox{\lstinline!a!} A}{B \hbox{\lstinline!a!} B}
\]
% Weird shift:
\newcommand\zlstinline{\let\par\endgraf\lstinline}
\begin{mathpar}
  \infer{A \hbox{\zlstinline!a!} B}{A \hbox{\zlstinline!a!} B}
\end{mathpar}
\end{document}
```